# Confused by results from simple calculation

Tags: python, python-3.x, average

I am not sure why the below code is not working. I am running this in python 3.5.2 and the problem appears to be in the calculation portion of the code. It returns no errors but gives huge values that shouldn't be the average of the 5 inputs.

```
#inputs
year1 = input("Enter wins for year 1: ")
year2 = input("Enter wins for year 2: ")
year3 = input("Enter wins for year 3: ")
year4 = input("Enter wins for year 4: ")
year5 = input("Enter wins for year 5: ")

#calculation
averageWin = int(year1 + year2 + year3 + year4 + year5) / 5
#output
print ("Average wins are", averageWin)
```

Comment: you are adding all the inputs as strings, so `'1' + '1' == '11'` you need to cast them each to an `int` then add them together.

Comment: Why not use a list called `year` and load it in a loop? Have a large number of variables like `year1` and `year2` isn't a good design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
    year = 0
    for i in range(5):
        ann = "{:,.0f}".format(i+1)
        year=year+input("Enter wins for year "+ann+": ")
    print year/5.
```

Shorter and works.

Comment: While this may work, it might be a good idea to also explain what was wrong with **his\her** code

Comment: Thanks! I will in the future. In this thread it has already been done.

Answer (score 1):

you need to cast the input values to integer individually

```
averageWin = (int(year1) + int(year2) + int(year3) + int(year4) + int(year5)) / 5
```

What you did before was concatenating the strings:

```
int('100' + '100') => int('100100') => 100100
```

Answer (score 0):

You are concatenating strings, and then turning that into an integer. You have to turn each individual string into an integer before adding them.

```
>>> a = '3'
>>> b = '5'
>>> c = '4'
>>> x = a+b+c
>>> int(x)
354
>>> x
'354'
>>> int(a)+int(b)+int(c)
12
```

Also, instead of naming individual variables, use a `list`.

```
>>> result = [int(input('Enter wins for year %d: ' % i)) for i in range(1,6)]
Enter wins for year 1: 3
Enter wins for year 2: 4
Enter wins for year 3: 3
Enter wins for year 4: 5
Enter wins for year 5: 5
>>> sum(result)/len(result)
4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

### By default, `input()` returns a string. You are adding the strings and then converting the result into an `int.`

Assume we have the inputs `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` as our variables. Your code does `'1'+ '2' + '3' + '4' + '5'` instead of `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5`. Your result is `'12345'` instead of `15`. So you are dividing 12345 by 5 instead of 15. To fix this, put `int()` around each of your `input()` calls, to convert those answers into numbers.